# Invalid type comparison when indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 columns in my dataframe currently set like this:

```
   A          B
True      Morning
True      Morning
False     Morning
False     Morning
```

But would like column B to show "Afternoon" when `column A = False`

```
A          B
True      Morning
True      Morning
False     Afternoon
False     Afternoon
```

However this returns the following error message. Any ideas?

```
df = mask.ix[mask["A"] == "True" , "B"] = "Afternoon"
Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py:792: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = getattr(x, name)(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-130-f98341f5041b>", line 1, in <module>
    df = mask.ix[mask["A"] == "True" , "B"] = "Afternoon"

  File "Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 855, in wrapper
    res = na_op(values, other)

  File "Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 794, in na_op
    raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems in your column A, the data type is `bool`  but you are comparing it against a string (`"True"`). Remove the quotation marks and it should work fine. Also, you may want to switch to `.loc`  instead of `.ix`  as it will be deprecated soon.

Also note that when the data type is already `bool`, you don't need to do `df['A']==True` or `df['A']==False`. You can just use `df['A']` and `~df['A']`  respectively.

```
df.loc[~df['A'], 'B'] = 'Afternoon'

df
Out: 
       A          B
0   True    Morning
1   True    Morning
2  False  Afternoon
3  False  Afternoon
```